# Between Two Cities, more than six offices

Tags: between-two-cities

The scoring card for Between Two cities shows points increasing to 21 for six offices.

How many points does seven or more offices score? Do you start counting them as a second set, or does the score cap out at 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The seventh office starts a new set

From [the rules](https://www.boardgamecapital.com/game_rules/between-two-cities.pdf):

> ### Offices (20 buildings + 8 duplex)
>
> **a set is worth 1|3|6|10|15|21, and a tile is worth +1 if next to at least 1 tavern**
>
> Offices score 1 point for one office tile,
> 3 points for two office tiles, 6 points for
> three, 10 points for four, 15 points for five,
> or 21 points for six office tiles (regardless
> of location or adjacency to each other).
>
> If a city has seven office tiles, the seventh starts a new set
> of offices, and the scoring starts over again at 1 for that set.
>
> *If a city has 7 office tiles, it scores 22 points for offices (21 + 1).*
>
> In addition, each office gets +1 point if it is adjacent to at
> least one tavern. Each office tile can only score
> 1 bonus point, but several offices can receive that point
> from the same adjacent tavern tile.
>
> *A single office adjacent to a tavern is worth 2 points (1 + 1). A
> single office adjacent to four taverns is still worth 2 points.*

The third paragraph (second unbolded paragraph) contains the answer to your question.